# publish ros2 message from yaml file

Tags: python, c++, ros

I am trying to run a single ros2 node which is part of the autoware universe. I recorded all input topics with `ros2 bag record` s.th. i now have several yaml files (cods snippet in the end) containing all sent messages. Now i want to publish those messages individually to run the node on its own. I cannot use `ros2 bag play` to run the simulation, but I need to write a publisher node which somehow gets the message from the yaml file and publishes it every x seconds e.g.
Is there a way to do that? Thank you in advance!

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1585897255
    nanosec: 366032919
  frame_id: map
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 89530.4904175517
      y: 42411.98934126079
      z: -3.608327379954426
    orientation:
      x: 0.003322876298139578
      y: -0.014172646821833243
      z: 0.8596727738629668
      w: 0.5106376567135674
  covariance:
  - 0.004823699025978851
  - 0.0014223050349292865
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -0.00033930002493972645
  - 0.0014223050349292876
  - 0.003066485845419473
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -0.00018709073063899757
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -0.0003393000249397263
  - -0.00018709073063899755
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 6.080293039040077e-05
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 13.072203929530296
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.008810670840086786
  covariance:
  - 0.03935738353508679
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -5.688005653640222e-11
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -5.688005653640594e-11
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0015608784670052972
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, currently not running ros, so none tested.

You can write a publisher node, that reads in the yaml file and publishes the content message continuously like this (using String message for illustration):

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from yaml import load

def load_message_from_yaml(path):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    yamlfile = load(f)
    f.close()
    return yamlfile

def talker(msg):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.loginfo(msg)
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    yaml_path = "/your/path"
    yaml_msg = load_message_from_yaml(yaml_path)
    try:
        talker(yaml_msg)
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

But you can also publish a yaml file from the command line directly via:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /your_topic_name your_msgs/YourMessage -f yourYamlFile.yaml
```

This will publish the contents of yourYamlFile.yaml to the topic /your_topic_name at a rate of 10 Hz.

See here the documentation for [rostopic](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_pub).